# Font awesome stacked icons alignment issue on Chrome

Tags: css, font-awesome, vuetify.js

In the screenshots, the icons with the numbers 9 and 2 are stacked fontawesome icons. I am using `vuetify` as my front end framework

On Firefox, my icons are showing correctly and in the same line as my other icons.

[image]

But in Chrome and Safari, they are not aligned

[image]

I have tried setting `display: inline`, but then the stacked icons are too high.

My button code is

```
<v-btn icon
    v-on="data.on">
    <span class="fa-stack fa-3x"></span>
    <v-icon color="green">fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x</v-icon>
    <strong class="fa-stack-1x text-primary">{{count}}</strong>
</v-btn>
```

How can i have these icons align with the key icon for chrome and other browsers?

Comment: How are you wrapping then, in `v-container`, `v-layout`, `v-flex` ? What's your wrapping logic ? Do you have a reproducible CodePen ?

Comment: @Toodoo this is from a component that is being used inside vuetify v-toolbar/v-toolbar-items tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears that the font awesome stack span adds a `2em` height, which doesnt both Firefox, but bothers Chrome. Overriding the height to 0em fixed the issue.